# Python alternative of ruby watirrecorder?

Tags: python, ruby, watir

I'm looking for a tool to record scripts for web application testing in python, similar to ruby watirrecorder. The latter is basically a tool that generates the script for watir (web application testing in ruby) which uses IE to test web applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Selenium, http://jimmyg.org/blog/2009/getting-started-with-selenium-and-python.html

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative may be Pamie, but not sure it is as mature as Selenium.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pamie/